# i3 WM (tiling manager) create popup window

Tags: python, linux, pygame, gtk

When I make a pygame window (I believe it uses SDL), it launches as a popup window, as I want, since then it doesn't affect the layout or visibility of elements. But if I launch a simple program using GTK and Cairo, it doesn't launch as a popup. Is there some specific env flag, signal, etc. that needs to be used to launch a window as a popup rather than a tiled window?

[pygame hello world code](https://inventwithpython.com/pygameHelloWorld.py)

[image: Pygame Hello World]

[cairo+gtk code, GTK Window section, past mid point of page](http://zetcode.com/gfx/cairo/cairobackends/)
[image: Cairo Hello World]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this in GTK, you need to call

```
gtk_window_set_type_hint((GtkWindow*)windowname, GDK_WINDOW_TYPE_HINT_DIALOG);
```

https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-type-hint

i3 will take window hints, and if a window tells i3 it is a dialog window, it will make it float automatically.

Comment: ... But you shouldn't do this. Your window is not a dialog, don't lie to the window manager. It is i3's job to manage windows, not yours. Your job is to deal with what the window manager decides. The user may still override this behavior anyway.

Comment: @IngoBürk, you are absolutely correct of course. There are cases, even in a tiling window manager, where things should float, but that should really be in the user's i3 config, not decided by some programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Get the WM_CLASS class or instance for the window with `xprop` and set `floating enable` for the window.

For example I have this in my i3 config

```
for_window [instance="Game of Life"] floating enable
```

Comment: I was looking for a way to do it without using i3 config because I know some program launched as a popup instead of tiled. I was interesting in knowing how I could program something to open as a popup